# Best practices for the development of security solutions

Tags: software, secure-coding, agile

IT firms developing security solutions (such as antivirus or Auth systems) are required to adopt a more sophisticated level of management and quality control while developing their products. Security firms must hire professionals to ensure the quality of the products meets the intended requirements and that best practices are implemented from the early stages of development.

To that end my question here are essentially to help IT security firms understand the best approaches in developing security solutions for their clients.

My question is: What are the best practices or industry standards in regards to security software development? More specifically what are the leading procedures and processes in regards to developing security solutions in terms of software development life cycle?

Comment: You mention the very thing you say you are looking for: SSDLC. There are detailed documents online that answer every one of your questions. I think you need to continue your research just a little longer. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Secure_SDLC_Cheat_Sheet https://www.cigital.com/blog/what-is-the-secure-software-development-lifecycle/ https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sdl/